# OR in conditional formatting formula brakes condition giving unexpected outcome

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a very unexpected outcome of OR used in conditional formatting formula.
Take a simple sheet:
[image: Simple sheet]

Now add conditional formatting with formula:

```
=B4:G7=$A$1
```

It works as expected, with true value for cells containing "A"

Now try another formula:

```
=OR(B4:G7=$A$1;FALSE)
```

Which should basically mean the same. Well.. the outcome is very different:
[image: Wrong highlight]

What's even more confusing is that chaging, for example, cell I7 to "a" influences the outcome:
[image: Even more bizarre effect]

This is exact formula I have used, with "LUB" being "OR", and "FAŁSZ" being "FALSE":
[image]

Edit:
I forgot to stand the question. Question is: why does it happens? How do I use OR correctly in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand how absolute and relative reference works in conditional formatting. Formula references refer to the very top left cell in the `applies to` range. If the formula has relative references, then for each `applies to` cell the cell in the  formula reference shifts accordingly, if absolute - then the reference does not change. In your case, the formula `=B4:G7=$A$1` is applied to cell `B4`, to cell `C4` - `=C4:H7=$A$1`, to cell `B5` - `=B5:G8=$A$1`, the same thing happens with formula `=OR(B4:G7=$A$1;FALSE)`.

Second, the formulas `=B4:G7=$A$1` and `=OR(B4:G7=$A$1;FALSE)` work completely differently. The first case actually compares the first cell of the range with `$A$1`, i.e. in the previous example `=B4=$A$1`, `=C4=$A$1`, `B5=$A$1`. In the second case, the range is divided into cells, they are compared with `$A$1` and the results are passed to the `OR` function, i.e. `=OR(B4:G7=$A$1;FALSE)` => `=OR(B4=$A$1;C4=$A$1;D4=$A$1 ... G7=$A$1;FALSE)` and if even if one is `TRUE`, then you also get the resulting `TRUE`.

Consequently, we can conclude that the following formula will work correctly for you in this case:

```
=OR(B4=$A$1;FALSE)
```

[image]